# dplyr to replace colnames with first row and remove first row using pipe function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to set the first row as the column names in my data, however my data consists of many factors which is causing some problems.

I am trying to complete this using the `dplyr` package.

`Str()` of the data:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ 1   : Factor w/ 2045 levels " 200039"," 200171",..: 2045 1
 $ 2   : Factor w/ 3 levels " DR"," GR"," OU": 3 2
 $ 1372: Factor w/ 1388 levels "       12","       15",..: 1388 1372
 $ 4   : Factor w/ 51 levels " ATLANTA             ",..: 21 4
 $ NA  : logi  NA NA
 $ 63  : Factor w/ 498 levels " 435"," 436",..: 498 63
 $ 95  : Factor w/ 264 levels " 1114"," 1115",..: 264 95
 $ 118 : Factor w/ 132 levels " Chain1  "," Chain10 ",..: 131 118
```

I am using the following code

```
x <- df %>%
  setNames(df[1, ])
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
     2045   3      1388                    21 NA  498   264       131
1 IRI_KEY  OU  EST_ACV   Market_Name          NA Open  Clsd  MskdName
2  200039  GR  9.709999  BUFFALO/ROCHESTER    NA  539  1219  Chain87
```

However I want the `IRI_KEY`, `OU`, `EST_ACV` etc. as the column names.

I am trying to complete this using `dplyr` since I will remove the first row and remove `V5` which is the `NA` column.

I would provide data but the data uses factors and the size is too big for SO. I provide the `head()` of the first 5 results.

```
       V1  V2        V3                    V4 V5   V6    V7        V8
1 IRI_KEY  OU  EST_ACV   Market_Name          NA Open  Clsd  MskdName
2  200039  GR  9.709999  BUFFALO/ROCHESTER    NA  539  1219  Chain87 
3  200171  GR  27.69099  MILWAUKEE            NA  522  9998  Chain97 
4  200197  GR     11.14  PEORIA/SPRINGFLD.    NA  903  9998  Chain59 
5  200233  GR  7.514999  OKLAHOMA CITY        NA 1122  1150  Chain102
```

EDIT: I uploaded some `dput()` here

https://textuploader.com/dn5vb

Comment: solve it upstream if possible, seems like you used `read.table` with default `header=FALSE` or something similar, it'll be much cleaner to deal with it at this step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
names <- sapply(df[1, setdiff(names(df), "V5")], as.character)
df %>% 
  select(-V5) %>% 
  set_names(., nm = names) %>%
  .[-1, ]
#  IRI_KEY OU  EST_ACV       Market_Name Open Clsd MskdName
#2  200039 GR 9.709999 BUFFALO/ROCHESTER  539 1219  Chain87
#3  200171 GR 27.69099         MILWAUKEE  522 9998  Chain97
#4  200197 GR    11.14 PEORIA/SPRINGFLD.  903 9998  Chain59
#5  200233 GR 7.514999    OKLAHOMA CITY  1122 1150 Chain102
```

Extract the first row except column `V5` and convert to character. In the pipe first exclude column `V5`, then change the column names and delete first row.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "       V1  V2        V3                    V4 V5   V6    V7        V8
IRI_KEY  OU  EST_ACV   Market_Name          NA Open  Clsd  MskdName
200039  GR  9.709999  BUFFALO/ROCHESTER    NA  539  1219  Chain87 
200171  GR  27.69099  MILWAUKEE            NA  522  9998  Chain97 
200197  GR     11.14  PEORIA/SPRINGFLD.    NA  903  9998  Chain59 
200233  GR  7.514999  'OKLAHOMA CITY'       NA 1122  1150  Chain102", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked great, I just had to make one correction to `set_names` and changed it to `setNames` - Thanks a lot!

Comment: ah so I did not have that loaded and used `dplyr`, thanks again!